# object not getting released in iphone

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks

```
 NSString *strSql = @"select tblrecentsearch_id,xmlrequest,company,postcode,city,kilometer,date from tblrecentsearch";

 returnValue = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [strSql UTF8String], -1, &selectStatement, NULL);
 if(returnValue == SQLITE_OK)
 {
  arrRecentSearch=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  while(sqlite3_step(selectStatement)==SQLITE_ROW)
  {
   Search *ObjSearch = [[Search alloc]init];
   ObjSearch.intRecentSearchId = sqlite3_column_int(selectStatement, 0);
   ObjSearch.xmlRequest = [NSString stringWithCString:(char  *)sqlite3_column_text_check(selectStatement, 1) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   ObjSearch.strCompnay=[NSString stringWithCString:(char  *)sqlite3_column_text_check(selectStatement, 2) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   ObjSearch.strPostCode=[NSString stringWithCString:(char  *)sqlite3_column_text_check(selectStatement, 3) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   ObjSearch.strPlace = [NSString stringWithCString:(char  *)sqlite3_column_text_check(selectStatement, 4) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   ObjSearch.strKilometer = [NSString stringWithCString:(char  *)sqlite3_column_text_check(selectStatement, 5) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   ObjSearch.strDate = [NSString stringWithCString:(char  *)sqlite3_column_text_check(selectStatement, 6) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

   [arrRecentSearch addObject:ObjSearch];

   [ObjSearch release];
  }
 }

 sqlite3_finalize(selectStatement);
```

I want release arrRecentSearch but it will return from function . How can i realese this array. Please help me.I am fetching data from databse.

Comment: return [arrRecentSearch autorelease];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just autorelease it :

```
return [arrRecentSearch autorelease];
```

Have a look at the [apple memopry management guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) for more information on how this works

If you are going to return an autoreleased object, you must remember to retain it if you wnat to keep it around later. i.e. if we have a function that returns an autoreleased array

```
- (NSArray *) getSearchResults {
    return [[[NSArray alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

and you want to remember the search results for later you must remember to do this :

```
...
NSArray *results = [[self getSearchResults] retain]; //!< Remember the retain here!
...
```

or, you might use a property to store it :

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *searchResults;

...
self.searchResults = [self getSearchResults]; //!< The property handles the retain for you here
...
```

Either way, if you just leave it as autoreleased, it's going to vanish and you're going to get an exception!

EDIT: Just realised MustISignUp has answered this in a comment!

Comment: Thank you but it generate uncaught exception

Comment: What's the exception? Is the method that gets arrRecentSearch remembering to retain it?

Comment: autorelease is the correct way to return an object, but the caller has to put it somewhere that will retain it or it will be released next time the autorelease pool is drained.

Comment: [Session started at 2010-05-28 19:58:25 +0530.]
2010-05-28 19:58:25.858 Handwerkersuche[1534:20b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[CFXPreferencesSearchListSource count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d474c0'
2010-05-28 19:58:25.860 Handwerkersuche[1534:20b] Stack: (

I am getting this exception

Comment: that tells me instantly that you've not retained it. Objective-C is trying to talk to an NSArray but is getting a CFXPreferencesSearchListSource instead. This means that the array has been released and the memory has been used for something else. I've edited my answer to show you how to fix this.

Comment: I am not getting exception now. Thank you